# Java JPA extending entity

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data

I have an Attachment class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ATTACHMENT")
public class Attachment implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_gen")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_gen", sequenceName = "attachment_seq", allocationSize = 1)
@Column(name = "ATTACHMENT_ID", nullable = false)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "CREATED_BY", nullable = false)
private User createdBy;

@Column(name = "FILE_NAME", nullable = false)
private String fileName;

@Column(name = "CONTENT_TYPE", length = 100, nullable = false)
private String contentType;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "CREATE_DATE", nullable = false)
private Date createDate;
```

and I want to extend this class with one additional field (which is on this table too):

```
@Entity
public class AttachmentWithContent extends Attachment {

@Column(name = "FILE_CONTENT")
@Lob
private byte[] fileContent;
```

And then I want to query that using JpaRepository:

```
 List<AttachmentWithContent> findByIdIn(List<Long> attachmentsIds);
```

but there's an error

```
'Attachment' domain type or valid projection interface expected here.
```

I need to be able to query Attachment class one time, and AttachmentWithContent another time.

I've tried with @Inheritance and @MappedSuperClass, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I think that message is only a warning by your IDE (I assume you use IntelliJ), because it deduces by the method name and repository type that you should return with a list of Attachment objects for that query.
I tried the entity model you described with a sample spring boot project and it works for me.
However, if you have an AttachmentRepository like this:

```
public interface AttachmentRepository implements JpaRepository<Attachment,Long>{
   List<AttachmentWithContent> findByIdIn(List<Long> attachmentsIds);
}
```

the *findByIdIn* method in this will only find the AttachmentWithContent entities; if you input an id that belongs to a simple Attachment, it will yield an empty result.
If you change the return type to Attachment (as the warning suggests) it will return all Attachments with or without content:

```
public interface AttachmentRepository implements JpaRepository<Attachment,Long>{
   List<Attachment> findByIdIn(List<Long> attachmentsIds);
}
```

Comment: I have this error:
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing column: DTYPE in ART.ART_ISSUE_ATTACHMENT
So it want to do it by inheritance, because it can't recognize which class to use.

Comment: did you create your database structure manually or did you generated it with hibernate?

Comment: edit:
by default, jpa uses the SINGLE_TABLE InheritanceType so Attachment and AttachmentWithContent will reside in an Attachment table which will have a DTYPE column for discriminating the two types